# Overwriting the JsonHttpResponseHandler class to add a param pass to onSuccess

Tags: java, android, google-maps, asynchttpclient, jsonresponse

OK i am not sure if i am asking the right question, but this is the only way i can think of to fix my problem.

I have to call an API to get information that needs to be used inside of this method.

```
public void setBuses(JSONArray theBuses)
{


    try {

        for(int x = 0; x < theBuses.length() ; x++)
        {

            busExists = false;
            if(x >= buses.size())
            {
                currentBus = new Bus();

            }
            else
            {
                busExists = true;
                currentBus = buses.get(x);
                currentMarker = busMarkers.get(x);
            }


            if(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).has("name"))
            {
                currentBus.setName(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).getString("name"));
            }
            if(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).has("driver"))
            {
                currentBus.setDriver(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).getString("driver"));
            }

            if(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).has("route"))
            {
                currentBus.setRoute(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).getString("route"));
            }
            if(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).has("active"))
            {
                currentBus.setActive(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).getBoolean("active"));
            }
            if(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).has("lastStop"))
            {
                currentBus.setLastStop(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).getString("lastStop"));
            }
            if(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).has("lastLong"))
            {
                currentBus.setLongi(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).getDouble("lastLong"));
            }
            if(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).has("lastLat")) {
                currentBus.setLat(theBuses.getJSONObject(x).getDouble("lastLat"));
            }



            if(currentMarker != null)
            {
                currentMarker.remove();
            }

            if(currentBus.isActive())
            {

                BusStop nextStop = routes.getNextStop(currentBus.getLastStop(), currentBus.getRoute());

                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.setTimeout(5000);
                client.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+currentBus.getLat()+"," +
                        ""+currentBus.getLongi()+"&destination="+nextStop.getLat()+","+nextStop.getLongi()+"&departure_time=1541202457&traffic_model=best_guess&key=AIzaSyCADdN-VW0vFCKz4uWqdL97Idk8ezENfHk"
                        , new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject distanceObject) {

                            setBusHelper(distanceObject);


                            }



                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

                            }



                        });

            }



            if(busExists) //this needs to be moved to the helper function and the varibles x, currentBus, mMap, and nextStop need to be passed to that function
            {
                Bus temp = buses.set(x,currentBus);
                Marker tempM = busMarkers.set(x,currentMarker);

            }
            else
            {
                buses.add(currentBus);
                busMarkers.add(currentMarker);
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

The pull from google calls this method to get the data from the API

```
    private void setBusHelper(JSONObject distanceObject) {
    String timeToNextStop = "Unknown";
    try {
        timeToNextStop = distanceObject.getJSONArray("routes").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("duration").getString("text");

        currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentBus.getLat(), currentBus.getLongi())).title("Time to Next Stop:" + timeToNextStop).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The problem i am having is since the call is aSync i don't have the marker to store in my array. I need to be able to pass the information i need for the adding of the marker and storage of the array to the onSuccess method in the JSONhandler. I have no idea how do this and i cant find any examples online. Any help you can provide would be very appreciated.

I will mention i have tried using SyncHttpClient but it does not seem to work synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the answer was to not use AsyncHttpClient at all. I used AsyncTask to call Apaches HTTP client which kept everything in the same thread and allowed me to make multiple calls. Program is working great now.